# How to pass as a props an array of String and JSX with NextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i passed as a props an array of strings an JSX but there is an error message "Missing "key" prop for element in arrayeslintreact/jsx-key "

```
<Sec1Header
    
      MainText={[
        "Your ",
        <span className='text-red-400'>
          Trusted
        </span>,
        " Development Partner",
      ]}
  
    />
```

I'm doing all of that to just try to color the text "Trusted" with different colors and not change the div dynamic

Comment: I suggest you make a child component for trusted span.

Comment: if you can tell me where to find this info or write the code because I am new to nextjs

Comment: Please follow the docs of react Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing your props in correctly, it's the [`react/jsx-key` ESLint rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-key.md) that's generating that message. You just need to add a `key` prop to that `<span>` tag:

```
<Sec1Header
  MainText={[
    "Your ",
    <span key="coloredText" className="text-red-400">
      Trusted
    </span>,
    " Development Partner",
  ]}
/>
```

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity...

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

But as one comment suggested, I would also convert that colored text into its own separate child component.